# How to change the background of a text bloc in a text document in Qt

Tags: qt, qt4

is there a way to change the background color of a QTextBlock in a QTextDocument without using a subclass of QAbstractTextDocumentLayout. I have tried many ways and the effects are null.  I am trying from the textCursor() method of a QPlainTextEditor and it seems practically everything is const.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try the merge methods:

```
QTextCursor cur = edit->textCursor();
QTextCharFormat fmt;
fmt.setBackground(QBrush(Qt::gray));
cur.mergeBlockCharFormat(fmt);
```

Comment: yeah i tried something similar yesterday: 
blkFormat= new QTextBlockFormat();        blkFormat->setBackground(QBrush(Qt::green,Qt::SolidPattern));       blkFormat->setForeground(QBrush(Qt::black,Qt::SolidPattern));
textCursor().setBlockFormat(*blkFormat);

So when I saw you using mergeBlockCharFormat() I figured that is what I was missing but I end up with the same result which is the program gets interrupted by the debugger:

Comment: i saw you using pointers to objects you create on heap (block formats) - there's really no need to do that (and hopefully you're cleaning them up after corresponding setBlockFormat()!) - just a warning

Comment: otherwise, can you post more code around the parts you're having trouble with? you need the text cursor point to the block (or a selection) you're modifying formats for.

Answer (score 2):

Could this example help you ?

http://qt.nokia.com/doc/4.6/demos-textedit.html

You can find it also in QtDemos, on Demonstrations->Text Edit.

Hope it helps!

Comment: Thanks, my bad I was only looking inside the examples and not the demos,  I wonder why they are not examples.

Comment: I wonder though if I will be able to do this programatically since the textedit only seems to modify the layout of a user selection.  I will see as I go through the code :D